# Which setting is limiting my active connections (ip_conntrack)?

Tags: nginx, debian, tcp, munin

I have a webserver with ispconfig (mysql & php & nginx). My munin statistic shows that there are the connecitons limited to about 9k. But I can't find a settings which is about 9000 which I could increase.

My system: Debian 9.8 / 128GB E5-1650v3 / nginx/1.10.3

My nginx settings are:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
```

Below are the the graphs which show the limit, all other graphs look normal.

Can you give me a hint which settings are responsible for the limited connections?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel E5-1650v3 has 12 threads if hyperthreading is active.
How many workers does your nginx use? If set to auto ("`worker_processes auto;`") it defaults to number of processors (12) and could limit your connections (12*768=9216). Increase `worker_processes` or `worker_connections`.

Have you checked your max open file (nofile) limits in /etc/security/limits.conf for the user running your nginx process?

Comment: Thx for the hint. I already have increased the worker_connections but then a lot of "Too many open files()" errors appear in log. Now I have increased the soft and hard file limit for the nginx process too and it works like a charm now.